# Do Saving Throw Bonuses Apply to Death Saving Throws?

Tags: dnd-4e, saving-throw

In D&D 4e, do death saving throws gain a benefit from powers, feats, features, etc. that provide a bonus to normal saving throws? Or are they considered wholly unique things?

This is, of course, assuming the effect doesn't normally end upon an unconscious state, such as stances. I'm speaking of such things as the feat Resilient Focus, or the handful of human racial feats that provide saving throw bonuses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**

From the Rules Compendium, p260 *(emphasis mine)*:

> **Death Saving Throw:** When an adventurer is dying, make a saving throw at the end of that character's turn each round. A death saving throw *works just like any other saving throw*, but the result determines how close the adventurer is to death.

If you get a bonus to all saving throws, that bonus *does* apply to death saves.

Comment: Furthermore, if your bonus to saving throws brings your death saving throw up to 20 or above, you can spend a healing surge just like if you had rolled a natural 20.